# Sendgrid- unble to concatinate plaintext along with html hyperlink

Tags: c#, sendgrid

I am using sendgrid to send an email but when I try to concatinate plaintext and html hyperlink it seems to be constructed correct but in email email I get html tag.

my code:

```
                string myHtml = string.Format(@"<a href='{0}'>here</a>", activationLink);
                string message = string.Format("Dear {0} {1}\n", FirstName, LastName) + "to verify your email address click ";
                SendMail(Email, subject, message, myHtml);
```

Below is my sendmail method:

```
    public bool SendMail(string To, string Subject, string Message, string htmlContent)
    {
        try
        {
            var client = new SendGridClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Key"].ToString());
            EmailAddress from = new EmailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["From"].ToString());
            var subject = Subject;
            EmailAddress to = new EmailAddress(To);
            string content = Message;
            //var htmlContent = "<strong>Hello, Email!</strong>";
            var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, content, htmlContent);
            var response = client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

This is what I get in email:

```
    here(Clickable)
```

what I want to appear in mail is:

```
    Dear User to verify your email address click here (Clickable)
```

Can anyone please help me.

Comment: That's all your adding as your HTML content? `myHtml` literally contains what you're seeing in your email. If you want it to contain something else, set it to something else.

Comment: Hi Charles, thank for a quick response. I am adding other contents to "content" parameter.

Comment: That's the plaintext version, not the HTML version.

Comment: so what should I do to get "Dear User to verify your email address click here (Clickable)"?

Comment: Write some HTML with that content?

Comment: do u mean  string myHtml = string.Format(@"<a href='{0}'>here</a>", activationLink);
                string message = string.Format("Dear {0} {1}\n", FirstName, LastName) + "to verify your email address click " + myhtml ;    and pass this to htmlcontent parameter?

Comment: I think it's maybe important to understand that you will most likely always see the html content. The text content is there for email clients that can't display html, as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks Charles Mager, your suggestion worked for me. Thank you sooo much :)